# Geometric sum with squared exponentials

Tags: summation

Is there a closed form of the following finite sum?
$$
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N}q^{n^2}
$$
where $q>0$. The only thing I found somehow related is the Jacobi $\theta$ elliptic function, but there it is an infinite sum.

Comment: If you can relate a summation to a special function, this is a good sign that no closed-form exists. Otherwise there would be no need for existence of the special function.